# Clojure - when is an atom dereferenced?

Tags: clojure, thread-safety

I'm confused with when atoms are dereferenced in Clojure. In the follow, I have a `server-request` function that receives data and updates the `request-result-data` which is just a map indexed by the request ID. The function blocks until the server has finished sending the data, and returns the request ID. The first snippet below works as expected. The second doesn't, because (it seems) @request-result-data is de-referenced before the function returns.

```
;works
(let [req-id (server-request "parameters")]
  (pprint (@request-result-data req-id)))

;returns nil
(pprint (@request-result-data (server-request "parameters"))))
```

Is this normal behaviour? Is there a better way to code this? As intuitively it doesn't seem I need a `let` here.

Thank you,

Comment: I missed the `and updates the request-result-data` part. Please show a [mcve] of the `server-request` function. Order matter when you're dealing with sequencing side effects, so it's hard to say for sure what the problem is without all the information.

Comment: Thanks - hard to put complete/verifiable example when dealing with server you don't have access to!

Comment: Well, maybe not a runnable example, but if we saw the function, it would be easier to explain the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

If the `server-request` function is modifying the `request-result-data` atom, then it's definitely true that you need to use the first form to make sure things happen in the right order. If you have a function call `(E1 E2)`, you shouldn't be relying on `E1` or `E2` being evaluated in any particular order.

Without any other context, I'd wonder why you can't have `server-request` return the information instead of putting it in an atom, but that goes beyond your original question.

Comment: Thanks - the server-request is a wrapper around a Java API that sends data asynchronously, and I'm caching the data in an atom until the request is finished.

Comment: "you shouldn't be relying on E1 or E2 being evaluated in any particular order" I don't think is true. The [evaluation model](https://clojure.org/reference/evaluation) guarantees that the function is evalauted, and then each of its arguments are evaluated, in that order.

Comment: Even so, I don't think that's a common understanding and so I'd argue it makes the code less readable.